# spring-integration poller synchronization-factory in advice-chain

Tags: spring, spring-integration

my goal is to let a spring-integration poller back off polling if several exceptions occur.

i have the following outbound-channel-adapter configured

```
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="adapter" ref="handler" 
        method="handle" channel="channel" >
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="50" fixed-delay="13"
             time-unit="SECONDS" task-executor="threadpool">
            <int:transactional synchronization-factory="mySyncFactory" 
                transaction-manager="simpleJdbcTransactionManager"
                timeout="30"/>
        </int:poller>   
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

now i want to add another advice (cuircuit breaker). for this i have to remove the int:transactional-tag an add an advice-chain instead. i can write that like this

```
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="adapter" ref="handler" 
        method="handle" channel="channel" >
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="50" fixed-delay="13"
             time-unit="SECONDS" task-executor="threadpool">
            <int:advice-chain>
                <tx:advice transaction-manager="simpleJdbcTransactionManager">
                    <tx:attributes>
                        <tx:method name="*" timeout="30000" />
                    </tx:attributes>
                </tx:advice>
                <int:ref bean="cuircuitBreaker"/>
            </int:advice-chain>
        </int:poller>   
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

i cannot find a possibility to declare a synchronization-factory for the tx-advice. any hints on how to realize this?

**UPDATE**
i am using spring-integration version 3.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have missed that `<int:advice-chain>` has the same `synchronization-factory` attribute and exactly for the same purpose.

And its description:

> Setting of this attribute will only have an affect if a Transaction advice is present in the chain.

Comment: `<tx:advice>` is out of Spring Integration scope, hence we don't have access to that component and should come up only with that solution for the parent tag. Since `<transactional>` and `<advice-chain>` are mutually exclusive it looks intuitive to have `synchronization-factory` on the `advice-chain` but not in the other place.